# How can I enable variations in Chrome from chromedriver options?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, chromedriver

How can I enable variations in Chrome from chromedriver options?

Hello, I'm facing a problem with Chrome where when I run an automated UI test with chromedriver, there's issues showing up (such as header is too high which covers other elements) but if I manually open up Chrome and perform the UI tests manually, the issues aren't there (the header looks correct).

I opened up `chrome://version` for both browsers and saw that the instance from automation does not have Variations listed, while the manual run had Variations listed.

I tried adding `options.addArgument("--reset-variation-state)` in hopes that it would enable it but it did not do anything.

I'll attach some screenshots
[image: Chrome with Variations]

This is chrome without Variations
[image: Chrome without Variations]

Answer (score 0):

So, this kinda worked for me. Currently researching better options.

If you go into `C:\users\[username]\AppData\local\Google\Chrome\User Data` and find your **"Local State"** file, there are two entries in there you should see values for -- **"variations_compressed_seed"** and **"variations_seed_signature"**

If you copy those values, and add them in your Chrome options before you start ChromeDriver, then variations should be enabled:

```
chromeOptions.AddLocalStatePreference("variations_compressed_seed", "[your compressed seed]");
chromeOptions.AddLocalStatePreference("variations_seed_signature", "[your seed signature]");
```

If you don't have those values in your Local State file, you can start Chrome with some dummy data directory, e.g. `start > run > chrome.exe --user-data-dir C:/Chrome`, then shut down chrome, go to `C:\Chrome\` and find the seed and signature in the **"Local State"** file that gets created in there.